# Bootstrap weather icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I need icons to show different weather conditions. Where can i find bootstrap icons for that, just like `fa-cloud`. I want icons for night, rain, snow, sleet, fog, cloudy etc. I am new to bootstrap and do not have much idea about these icons.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you are looking for is not provided by default on Bootstrap.

But on the other hand, here is a font icon library inspired by Font Awesome though as you wanted. This is perfect for your situation.

[Weather Icons](https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/)

Comment: thnx, i will check this

Comment: I am using this https://erikflowers.github.io/weather-icons/, but for some reason, the icon does not display. I have copied the font files to the font directory, the .css files to the CSS folder. Font and CSS folders are in the same level. I used <p><i class="wi wi-day-hail"></i></p> but i just get squar. No icons. Any help please.

Comment: Are you including the `weather-icons.min.css` file in your HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of the icons that Bootstrap comes with here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

You'll probably need to expand your search to a separate icon library such as [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) to get what you want.

Comment: thnx, let me check this